# Nodejs + Mongojs: convert string to document

Tags: string, node.js, mongodb, document

I'm trying to insert a new document into my collection, by getting the data from url and i have to sew them together, so at the end i have a string.
How can i convert my string into a document?

```
var x={name:"peter"};
```

This works fine if i pass it to the insert function.

```
var x='{name:"peter"}';
```

This is what i have, and i would like to pass this somehow to insert.

Comment: What kind of data?  How are you sewing them together?  What format is this string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse()`

Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Node.js has JSON by default, so you can just use it.

Example:

```
var object = JSON.parse("{hello:'world'}");
```

will give you an object which you can persist to MongoDB.

Comment: I can't make it work with json. Either the format of my string is bad for json.parse, or the parsed json isn't good for the insert function.

Comment: Then give us an example of what your strings do look like.